# php $_POST[] not set after submiting

Tags: php, post

I have checked all the form action and method, all correct. I really wonder why it is like this. I use this for many times and this time I can't find anything wrong. When I debug the $_POST['name'] and all other array contents, it shows that there no value set, all 'NULL'.

HTML:

```
<form class="contact2-form validate-form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <span class="contact2-form-title">
            Contact Us
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
        <input class="input2" type="text" name="name">
        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="NAME"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
        <input class="input2" type="text" name="email">
        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="EMAIL"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Message is required">
        <textarea class="input2" name="message"></textarea>
        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="MESSAGE"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Input the answer">
        <input class="input2" type="text" name="validator">
        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="8 + ? = 17"></span>
    </div>
    <input class="input2" type="hidden" name="domain" value="ywsample.com">
    <div class="container-contact2-form-btn">
        <div class="wrap-contact2-form-btn">
            <div class="contact2-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_request" value="Send Request" class="contact2-form-btn">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_request'])) {
        if ($_POST['validator'] == "9") {
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $success = sendAdminEmail($date);
        } 
        else {
            $redo = "Your validation answer is not correct";
        }
    }
    else {
        $redo = "Something went wrong, please try again later.";
    }
```

As asked the full code is here in a txt file. I can't paste it here, many display errors occur.
https://www.ynw.com.au/ynw-demo/contact/index.txt 
You can directly copy the file and change the file extension to php to test it.

Comment: Please show the actual output from `var_dump($_POST);` in your question

Comment: It works for me when I submit the form. Could you give us more details please?

Comment: are you sure about the index.php page ? try using an empty string instead and see

Comment: Like John says, a `var_dump($_POST)` is needed here. On second note, having a fixed value for your validator kind of defeats the purpose of having a validator at all

Comment: It might b the problem with your form action ! Are you sure this is the right page ?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) OUTPUT : array(0) { }